# Postgresql: Getting transactions in given data range

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

Let's assume, that there is a table which contains data about transactions with dates:

```
+----+------------------+
| id |    localdate     |
+----+------------------+
|  1 | 2017-10-16 10:00 |
|  2 | 2017-10-16 10:01 |
|  3 | 2017-10-16 10:02 |
|  4 | 2017-10-16 10:06 |
|  5 | 2017-10-16 10:20 |
|  6 | 2017-10-16 10:26 |
|  7 | 2017-10-16 10:45 |
|  8 | 2017-10-16 10:46 |
|  9 | 2017-10-16 10:47 |
| 10 | 2017-10-16 10:48 |
| 11 | 2017-10-16 10:49 |
+----+------------------+
```

Now, there are two filters that user can set in application: data range and transactions limit. User should see count of all transactions which occured more times than tranasction limit in given data range. 
For example when transactions limit will be set to 3 and data range to 15 minutes, I would need to get all transactions which occured at least 4 times in any 15 minutes.
So in above table it will be (transaction ids): 4, 10, 11

I tried to do it with use of window functions, but couldn't fully make it. Does anyone have idea how to do it?

Comment: Important consideration: do you mean any sliding 15 minute window, or within one clock quarter `:00-:14`, `:15-:29`, etc? If there are 2 transactions at `10:59` and two at `11:01` does that match, or not match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it can be achieved by window functions, use sub-statments:

```
with data as (select unnest(tim)::timestamp tim from (select 
          array[
            '2017-10-16 10:00',
            '2017-10-16 10:01',
            '2017-10-16 10:02',
            '2017-10-16 10:06',
            '2017-10-16 10:20',
            '2017-10-16 10:26',
            '2017-10-16 10:45',
            '2017-10-16 10:46',
            '2017-10-16 10:47',
            '2017-10-16 10:48',
            '2017-10-16 10:49'
          ] tim) a)
       select tim from (   
        select a.tim, (select count(1) from data where tim >= a.tim - interval '15 minutes' and tim <= a.tim and tim <> a.tim) + 1 cnt from (
         select * from data
        ) a 
      ) a where cnt >= 4
```